# Solar Radiation Environmental Test Duration

Tags: mechanical-engineering, environmental-engineering, product-testing

I am designing an outdoor sensor and I need to test it for continuous outdoors service. One of the test I wish to perform is a solar radiation test for the actinic effect (like procedure 2 in MIL-STD-810). I want to examine how the sensor will behave under continuous thermal radiation from the sun. 
The problem is that MIL-STD-810 states that I have to make a 56 days long test, which is not practical. If I go to civil standards like IEC60068-2-5 then they do not suggest a test duration at all.

How would you test an outdoors unit to validate it's integrity under long time solar radiation?

Thanks in advance!
Eli

Comment: Test it in real conditions. Which is why the mil spec requires 56 days.

Comment: Standard Weatherometer testing minimum  ( UV lamps plus water and or salt spray) is 1,000  Hr, about 5 weeks.